# Is there a good Latex compilation error summary tool for VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, pdflatex

I'm trying to find a nice latex compilation error summary tool that plugs into VSCode. I've done some searching on the extensions marketplace but am struggling to find what I'm looking for.

I'm hoping to find something similar to the Overleaf error summary tool. Overleaf has a really nice builtin tool that interprets and summarizes the Latex logs in a very readable format. In short it does two things:

1. It catches all error in the latex compilation process and puts them in a list.
2. It categorizes the errors into critical (ie. compilation breaking) or simply warnings.

I would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: look at adding a `problemMatcher` to the task

Comment: Have a look at the latex compilation tools ltx2any. This provides a nicely formatted summary of errors and warnings in several formats, e.g. as pdf, markdown...